# How can I configure zsh completion to launch a menu - for command options?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

If I am `cd`'ing into a directory, there is a setting in my `~/.zshrc` that tells zsh to always launch a menu when I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> on an ambiguous completion, e.g.

- `~% cd /etc/a` <kbd>tab</kbd>

will immediately cause a menu to launch

~/.zshrc

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*' menu yes select
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s%p
```

What Im trying to do is get the same behaviour but for command **options**,
e.g.

- `~% rsync -` <kbd>tab</kbd>

What is currently happening is I get:

> zsh: do you wish to see all 405 possibilities (136 lines)?

How can I get a menu to launch immediately like zsh does on `cd` completion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just guessed at some variations of the menu command and this worked

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu yes select
```

Comment: The `yes` seems to be optional [https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/zsh#Command_completion].